# Schedule time exact tasks in Android for a short interval

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timer, schedule

Application has running ForegroundService. While this service is running it needs to execute some tasks every 5 seconds. It's important to measure time interval in elapsed system time.

- Handler.postDelayed
- Timer
- ScheduledExecutorService
- Kotlin coroutines
- RxJava

All of them work in uptime and affected by cpu sleep.
Official documentation recommends to use AlarmManager for time exact tasks, but for such short intervals it won't work and lead to "excessive wake up" warning.
Keeping wakelock preventing cpu sleep will cause severe battery use by app.

So my question is: how to schedule task which will be executed in a short time interval (few seconds), where time is measured on elapsed time timeline?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't think I could help you as you describe your problem since my go-to answers are things you have already tried. But if you don't mind, could you describe the task that you want to be repeated every 5 seconds? Maybe there's a different way to approach th issue in general.

Comment: Basically app shall verify if several types of data match to a condition. For instance: amount of received locations for period of time. It can't be data driven, because locations could stop arriving if GPS signal lost.